# Access a property from another property in controller

Tags: php, symfony, properties, controller, entity

I'm bulding a webapp in Symfony, and I need to access to some properties of an entity in a controller to add this values to $candidature entity. Thank you for the help.

Controller.php :

```
class CandidatureController extends AbstractController
{
#[Route('/candidature', name: 'app_candidature')]
public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $candidature = new Candidature();

    //$candidatNom = $entityManager->getRepository(ProfileCandidat::class)->findBy($Nom);

    $candidature->setNom($candidatNom);
    $candidature->setPrenom('Charles');
    $candidature->setCv('cv');
    $candidature->setPostId('4');

    $entityManager->persist($candidature);
    $entityManager->flush();
    return $this->render('candidature/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'CandidatureController',
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$candidatNom = $entityManager->getRepository(ProfileCandidat::class)->findBy(['nom' => $Nom);
```

should do the trick

Comment: It's returning me undefined variable $Nom

Comment: ah I see. I think you want to SEARCH by $Nom? How do you want to search? you can search using post form submission which would be standard and the solution you should go for. Or you can do, to start, simpler, via route parameter.
`#[Route('/candidature/{Nom}', name: 'app_candidature')]` 
`public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, string $Nom): Response`
then call it via `/candidature/francois`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-http-methods

Comment: @Blacknwhite what I strongly recommend to you is that you pay 25$ and make a 1 month subscription to symfonycasts. I am not affiliated. But they have a full course on symfony 5 and 6. Just do that once, and you should get going fast. Figuring all of this out yourself will take forever. Not worth 25 dollars

Comment: The answer of @Toskan is good enough for your code, however FYI, an alternative could be the use of annotation `ParamConverter` check doc: https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html